# Migration alterar apenas o valor default de um campo - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migrations

Quero lançar uma migração que atualize somente o valor default de um campo, tentei da seguinte forma :

```
 $table->string('mikrotik_rate_limit')->default('1048576/1048576');
 $table->bigInteger('mikrotik_recv_limit')->default(1073741824);
 $table->bigInteger('mikrotik_xmit_limit')->default(1073741824);
```

mas não deu certo pois obviamente o campo já existe então ele entendeu que eu queria criar um novo então deu alerta de campo duplicado. Gostaria de saber como posso corrigir isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente deve ser feito algo similar a um alter table do sql. Na documentação do laravel tem um guia para isso: [modificando colunas](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#modifying-columns). 
Basicamente você cria uma migration e acrescenta a função change()
no exemplo que você colocou:

```
$table->string('mikrotik_rate_limit')->default('1048576/1048576')->change();
$table->bigInteger('mikrotik_recv_limit')->default(1073741824)->change();
$table->bigInteger('mikrotik_xmit_limit')->default(1073741824)->change();
```

Para isso você deve adicionar o doctrine/dbal ao seu composer.json e executar a instalação.